# find the sum of random numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

Tossing Dice
To roll the dice Which the points are always low The total points must be between 1-10.
By rolling the dice, three dice will be thrown, with the front of the dice able to score from 1-6. But the total points must
not exceed 1-10. Here, proceed to the console. .log () numbers to be displayed or use to show any type of information you like
, using your own language
The sample file will be the javascript used for
Example answer 3 6 1 = 10

Comment: Please try to do your homework alone and come here only when you have some piece of code to show

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Math.random()</h2>


<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = getRndInteger(1,7)">Click Me</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = getRndInteger(1,7)">Click Me</button>

<p id="demo2"></p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = getRndInteger(1,7)">Click Me</button>

<p id="demo3"></p>

<script>
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this :

```
    var max_dice1 = 7;
    var min = 1;
    var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_dice1 - min)) + min;
    var max_dice2 = 10 - dice1;

    var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_dice2 - min)) + min;
    var max_dice3 = max_dice2 - dice2;

    var dice3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_dice3 - min)) + min;

    var total = dice1+dice2+dice3;
```